# Cloning list element with button

Tags: jquery, list, clone

Have a bit of problem with the jQuery clone() functionality. Basically I have a list:

```
<ul id="portfolio">
 <li id=1><button class="save">content...</button></li>
 <li id=2><button class="save">content...</button></li>
 <li id=3><button class="save">content...</button></li>
 <li id=4><button class="save">content...</button></li>
 <li id=5><button class="save">content...</button></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to clone the content of a specific list whenever the user hits that lists "save" button. So far I have this jQuery:

```
$('.save').click(function() {
 var id = 1;
 $('#portfolio li').each(
  function() { 
    $(this).attr('id', 'id' + id++); 
 });
 $('#id1').clone().appendTo('#drop');
});
```

This code makes enables the user to clone #id1 so it is a start. But how can I get the functionality I'm looking for?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target the save button, and clone the parent.

```
$('.save').click(function() { $(this).parent('li').clone().appendTo('#drop'); });
```

**[Here's an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xGdJC/)**

**Important Note: You should change the ID of the clones item so that there won't be any collisions!**

Comment: This is what I had in mind too, but I think it suffers from the same issue his code does.  Only the first 5 would be 'active'.  You would have to reload the page to get the new buttons to be 'linked' too ... or at least that's how jsfiddle is handling it.

Comment: Note that the clones are not appended on the same list! `#drop != #protfilio`. If he wanted that those elements would be able to clone too, he'll need to use `live` or the 1.7 equivalent: `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
      var count = parseInt($('#portfolio').val());
      var newHTML = [];
      for(var i=0;i<count+1;i++){
        newHTML.push('<ul id=' + count+i ' +'><button class="save">content....</button>');
      }
      $('#portfolio').html(newHTML.join(''));
    });
});
```

That ul and li is what's making it even more difficult than it has to be.  It's a lot simpler if you use  and then in code do 'id='.